# What is the meaning of the second line of a .dqy file?

Tags: sql, excel

I use .dqy files for ages to create Excel output for a query. The contents of a .dqy file look like this:

```
XLODBC
1
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDatabase;UID=MyUser;Pwd=MyPwd
select * from Customer
```

It's evident that the first line is the driver, the 3rd line is the connection string and the 4th line is the query. So far, I never cared about the second line of this file, I always wrote "1" here because I saw this somewhere. But what is the meaning of this "1"? Now I've made some experiments so that I wrote random strings here and the query always worked unless the string contained a TAB character. But what is the intended content of this line?